# When could a Spark job fail with FetchFailedException?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a requirement, where I need to join few hive tables and fetch the final data that comes out of that query and then write that data to a file.

I am able to achieve this requirement, but when there were many jobs running in the system, I found one of the job which has above use case was failing, I was trying to debug further to find the actual root cause of this failure, but I could not succeed in it.

Can some one help me on this. Here I am attaching a complete log of this job execution.
[Complete Log file of my Spark Job](https://www.hightail.com/download/ZWJYS3hVQXA1aWE5TE1UQw)

Answer (score 1):

The `MetadataFetchFailedException` can occur when executors are lost unexpectedly due to some unhandled exception, usually memory-related if it's intermittent rather than all executors getting lost, but potentially also if other unhandled errors occur due to malformed individual data records, etc.

The following lines in your log file confirms lost executors:

```
15/12/03 18:55:30 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 7 on my_cluster_ip3: remote Akka client disassociated
15/12/03 18:55:30 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@my_cluster_ip3:54584] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/12/03 18:55:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for 7 from TaskSet 4.9
15/12/03 18:55:30 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 4.9 (TID 3106, my_cluster_ip3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 lost)
15/12/03 18:55:30 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 4.9 (TID 3109, my_cluster_ip3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 lost)
15/12/03 18:55:30 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 4.9 (TID 3103, my_cluster_ip3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 lost)
```

Since you're running on YARN, one common cause of OOM-related lost executors when using YARN is that YARN enforces its container memory limits, but for Spark, you need to guess at the executor memory overhead fitting in to the same container as the task which gets to use up to `spark.executor.memory` bytes of memory.

You're probably using the default `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` of 384. It looks like your containers have a maximum of ~24GB, so I'd suggest cranking up `spark.executor.memory` and/or `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` somewhat to see if it helps. You could try to crank it up as high as it can go and see if that fixes it first, and then crank down to what you actually need (possibly with guidance from reported metrics/stats) to avoid stranding cores.

Comment: I tried with various values for following parameters, in normal cases it is working well. But when I keep increasing the load (ran more than 15 jobs) then at least one job is failing.  Parameters that I tried : --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 2G.  I am trying to understand more on this. If any one has come across with the same situation, your inputs will definitely help us.

Comment: The reason for `MetadataFetchFailedException` is certainly when Spark cannot get a so-called `MapStatus` for a Spark executor which can also be due to GC and so increasing the memory may not what you want in few cases.